# Duplicate (ish) rows returned. How to eliminate?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm NOT well versed in SQL or SQLITE.

I'm running a simple select and join statement.  I'm basically pulling contacts from a sqlite3 database and dumping out into a csv, manually.

The problem I'm running into is, I've got names and ID's in one table, phone numbers and labels in another.  Where, label means "Mobile", "Work", etc.

So I'm joining where the name's ID = to the phone number's owner ID.

What I'm finding (and this makes perfect sense) is that if I have three phone numbers for one person, that one person shows up three times.

IE:

```
John Doe, 123-123-1234, Home, someInc
John Doe, 123-123-4321, Mobile, someInc
John Doe, 123-456-3214, Work, someInc
```

Now.. how do I, through the actual SQL statement itself, get results more like this:

```
John Doe, 123-123-1234, Home, someInc
          123-123-4321, Mobile, someInc
          123-456-3214, Work, someInc
Foo Barr, 987-654-3211, Home, anotherInc
[...]
```

Comment: Don't do this in your query... instead, hide values for presentation purposes in your front end.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson - why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want to flatten the table:

```
select n.name,
       max(case when p.label = 'home' then p.phonenumber end) as PhoneHome,
       max(case when p.label = 'work' then p.phonenumber end) as PhoneWork,
       max(case when p.label = 'mobile' then p.phonenumber end) as PhoneMobile
from names n join
     phones p
     on n.nameid = p.nameid
group by n.name
```

This puts each type of phone number in a separate column.  You need to research all the different labels to get the right columns.

You can also put all the phone numbers into one field, something like "home:0001112222,work:33344455555:

```
select n.name,
       group_concat(p.tag||':'||p.phonenumber) as AllNumbers
from names n join
     phones p
     on n.nameid = p.nameid
group by n.name
```

Comment: I really like this answer.  I'm going to try it out and accept it if it works.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks so much for this Gordon.  I ended up selecting also the owner ID from the phone number table, and grouping by first name, last name, and phone number.  The result is I get 3x entries if there are three phone numbers, but I can sort/order by id and post-process the duplicates easily.  The problem I ran into doing it purely your way without modification was if I had say, two mobile numbers for one contact; I then would get only one line but lose one phone number. I decided having duplicates and post-processing was better but used the majority of your code to get me there. Thanks again.

Comment: @Harv . . . I 2 duplicates are the max, you could tweak the query to have `min` and `max`.  However, that doesn't generalize, so the post processing may be the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. Copy the data as-is to Excel and apply the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942588/combine-multiple-rows-with-same-value-into-one-plus-more-in-excel).
2. Do it with slightly different SQL which will work if you have some unique ID on your `Phones` table:

   ```
   SELECT 
       CASE t.rank WHEN 1 THEN t.Name ELSE '' END as Name,
       t.Phone,
       t.Work 
   FROM (
       SELECT  t.*, 
           (
               SELECT  COUNT(*)
               FROM    yourTable ti
               WHERE   t.phoneID >= ti.phoneId
           ) AS rank
       FROM  yourTable t
       ORDER BY phoneID
   )
   ```