# Spreadsheet formula to gather all matches into one cell if matches exist

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm using the formula in the answer to this post:
[Spreadsheet formula to gather all matches into one cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228847/spreadsheet-formula-to-gather-all-matches-into-one-cell)

My version is:

```
=ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(REPT(Occupation!B:D&", ",Occupation!A:A=A2)))
```

Some of my Occupation!B:D cells are empty, though, so I'm getting results like "Attorney, , , ".

My question is where would I add an IFERROR or ISBLANK or IF <> "" so that nothing is returned if any of the cells on Occupation!B:D are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, FILTER(Occupation!B:D, Occupation!A:A=A2))
```

and see if that helps?

### REFERENCE

- [textjoin()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly. I added a little to handle totally empty returns: =IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, FILTER(Occupation!B:D, Occupation!A:A=A5)),"")

Comment: The cool thing is it finds and concatenates results vertically AND horizontally, too.