# Use one lookup to generate multiple values

Tags: excel

I have an array filled with product orders that have multiple products.

```
Order #    Product
N-122      C135
N-122      P223
N-122      C134
N-134      P223
```

I have seen other threads merge products into one row that have the same order.
[Excel Macro - Rows to Comma Separated Cells (Preserve/Aggregate Column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502248/excel-macro-rows-to-comma-separated-cells-preserve-aggregate-column)

Is there a way to lookup my order values without merging the products into one row?

I want to create a table in another sheet that once the Order # is input it will show all of the products associated with it on multiple rows.

```
Order #     Product
N-122       C135
            P223
            C134
```

Comment: Why don't you use PivotTable?

Comment: I need to give this spreadsheet to the sales team, and they are not very excel savvy. I wanted something that they would just plug in a value, and wouldn't need to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andre mentioned you can use a Pivot Table but if you still want to do a formula then you can do this

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$5,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$5=$D$1,ROW($A$2:$A$5)-1),ROW(A1)),2),"")`

Note this is an Array formula and you have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

See this screenshot

[image]

Once you enter the formula in `E1`, simply drag it down to find matches.