# How to create sublist from list

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, excel-2010

Below is an example of the original column's information and the data I want to extract (using a formula, not a filter).

Where List 1 is column A and List 2 is column B. Example:

**List 1**:

```
1 Ok
2 Ok
3 Ok
4 Ok 
5 FC34534534534
6 Ok
7 Ok
8 Ok
9 FC34534576878
```

**List 2**:

```
1 FC34534534534
2 FC34534576878
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated as always!

To be clear - I don't want to copy/paste, sort or do anything but have the formula work this out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use one lookup to generate multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095408/use-one-lookup-to-generate-multiple-values)

Comment: Seems to be very similar! Thanks for this although its already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that list 1 is in column A:A, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$9,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$9<>"Ok",ROW($A$1:$A$9),9.99E+207),ROW())),"")
```

In cell C1 (the column is not important, but the row is since we have the function `ROW()` in the formula).

Then drag down.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this is an array formula and as such will work properly **only** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Jerry, I have my spreadsheet with the above values in excel in Column A rows 1 - 9, copied in your formula to cell C and dragged down, and all cells are blank :(

Comment: @Lance Oops, my bad, I forgot to mention that this is an array formula. Use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to use it. After doing this for the first formula, you can drag it down the usual way.

Comment: Jerry - many thanks for the tip! The {} around formulas as I searched the web for this in examples was doing my head in! That being said, it seems that all this does is repeats the entire list ?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that the numbers on the left are row numbers and that your list is in ColumnA without a header, and based on Excel 2007:

1. Put `=IF(A1="OK","",A1)` in B1 and copy down to suit.
2. Copy ColumnB and Paste Special values over the top.
3. Select enough of ColumnB and replace nothing with say "".
4. Then replace "" with nothing.
5. Go To Special and select Blanks.
6. Delete with Shift cells up.
7. Tidy to suit.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this, but I'm not seeking for a list of steps to perform this as I could just filter the column... I'm hoping for a formula that just does what is required.