# excel macro to combine B column cells based on A Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a macro from another related question ([Excel Macro - Rows to Comma Separated Cells (Preserve/Aggregate Column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502248/excel-macro-rows-to-comma-separated-cells-preserve-aggregate-column)) and am getting a Runtime Error 1004.

When trying to debug, it says that this line is the problem:
**oCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = sResult**

Here is the macro:

Sub GroupMyValues()

```
Dim oCell As Excel.Range
Dim sKey As String
Dim sResult As String

Set oCell = Worksheets(2).Range("A1")

While Len(oCell.Value) > 0

    If oCell.Value <> sKey Then

        'If first entry, no rows to be deleted
        If sKey <> "" Then

            oCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = sResult

        End If

        sKey = oCell.Value
        sResult = oCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Set oCell = oCell.Offset(1, 0)

    Else

        sResult = sResult & ", " & oCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        Set oCell = oCell.Offset(1, 0)
        oCell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete

    End If

Wend

'Last iteration
**oCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = sResult**
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You can't offset one row above Row Number 1.